# WSUSUTIL SQL Database Gives Multiple Errors

Tags: sql, wsus

I have a secure connection setup for WSUS and I am trying to connect to my SQL SUSDB. When I do that I have tried multiple connections and it has given me the following for each:

- SERVER.DOMAIN.NET,PORT\INSTANCE - No Such Host is Known
- SERVER.DOMAIN.NET\INSTANCE - A network-related or instance-specific    error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL  Server. The server was not found or inaccessible.
- SERVER\INSTANCE - Failed to start and configure WSUS service.

I can connected the SQL with my other databases. using the top method. Why is WSUS much more of a pain?